# Check for empty observable object

Tags: angular

I have this html-tamplate

```
<div *ngIf="results$ | async; else notFound">
...
</div>
<ng-template #notFound>
<div>
  <h2>Not found</h2>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

results$ is an Observable object, which is initialized in component and contains 3 different arrays. How can I check whether my $results is empty(actually check if all of arrays in this object empty) in

```
*ngIf
```

so in template will be shown.

```
<ng-template #notFound>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngIf="results$ | async as threeArrays>
  <div *ngIf="!allArraysAreEmpty(threeArrays); else allArraysEmpty">
    ...
  </div>
  <ng-template #allArraysEmpty>
    <div>
      <h2>All 3 arrays are empty</h2>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Says that allArraysAreEmpty is not a function. Is there any other possible variants to solve my problem? I`m kind of new in Angular. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, of course, you need to write that method in your component. That should be trivial if you know what the actual type of the threeArrays variable is (we don't: we just know that it's something that has 3 arrays).

Comment: Yeah, of course it's custom function :). Thanks a lot, problem is resolved